# How should I backup MongoDB on DigitalOcean?

Tags: mongodb, backup, database-backups, digital-ocean

I have a MongoDB (3.0.4) instance running on a DigitalOcean node (as a Docker container with a persistent data volume), how should I ensure that its data gets backed up regularly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using [MongoDB's Cloud Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/), which has a [backup](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/backup) service.